# I have 2 errors but only one of them is working

Tags: php

whatever I enter I get the same error "all fields are required" but this error should appear only when field/s is empty.
I have other error should appear when I enter incorrect details but I keep only getting the first error.
I'm a beginner and I had one hour reviewing my code but I still can't solve it by myself :/

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    //display index
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) or ($password)) {
            $error = 'All fileds are required';
        }else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ? ");

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {

                //user entered correct details
            }else {
                // user enterde false details
                echo $error = 'Incorrect details!';
            }

        }
    }
    ?>

    <html>

    <head>
        <title>CMS Tuterial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

        <br /><br />

        <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
            <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small>
            <br /><br />
        <?php } ?>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />

        </form>

    </div>

    </body>

    </html>


    <?php
}


?>
```

Comment: `if (empty($username) or ($password))` should be `if (empty($username) or empty($password))`.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.